# Optimize query with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query .its execution took 15 min .It is too much slowly .

Is there a way to optimize it ?

### **Query**

```
SELECT
 Id,Fees,WeekOfMonth,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), StartDate, 103) AS StartDate,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), EndDate, 103) AS EndDate,'Temp Fees                      ' AS FeesName 
  ,@MonthName AS [MonthName]
  INTO ##TempFeesMonthly
  from
  (
SELECT DISTINCT 
1 as Id,sum(((CNTI_THPAYE *(CNTI_THFACT / CNTI_THPAYE)) *
(CASE WHEN CNTI_DURHEBDO IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CNTI_DURHEBDO/5 END)*@NumberOfDays)) AS Fees,WeekOfMonth,StartDate,EndDate
FROM SCHHAYS.dbo.WTVTAT TAT
      LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTTIEINT INT 
        ON (
            TAT.TIE_ID = INT.TIE_ID
        ) 
        AND (
            TAT.VTAT_IORDRE = INT.TIEI_ORDRE
        )     
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.PYCONTRAT CC 
        ON TAT.PER_ID = CC.PER_ID 
        AND TAT.CNT_ID = CC.CNT_ID     
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.CMTIERS T 
        ON TAT.TIE_ID = T.TIE_ID    
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTMISS M 
        ON CC.PER_ID = M.PER_ID 
        AND CC.CNT_ID = M.CNT_ID     
    LEFT JOIN
    ##WTCNTIWeek COT1 
        ON M.PER_ID = COT1.PER_ID 
        AND M.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID    
    INNER JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTPRH AS PRH 
        ON M.PER_ID = PRH.PER_ID 
        AND M.CNT_ID = PRH.CNT_ID 
        AND M.TIE_ID = PRH.TIE_ID     
    INNER JOIN
    ##tempStartEndWeekDates AS Tsed 
        ON     PRH_DTEDEBSEM>=Tsed.StartDate 
        AND PRH_DTEFINSEM<=Tsed.EndDate     
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTSCCT C 
        ON CC.RGPCNT_ID = C.RGPCNT_ID 
        AND CC.PER_ID = C.PER_ID 
        AND CC.CNT_ID = C.CNT_ID   
    INNER JOIN
    ##TempHaysStaffWeek HF 
        ON C.VAPO_CODE = HF.onetouch  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
group by
WeekOfMonth,StartDate,EndDate)t

--CREATE INDEX IDX_TempFeesMonthly ON ##TempFeesMonthly(WeekOfMonth)
--Calcul Temp Margin 
UNION ALL
--INSERT INTO ##TempFeesMonthly(Id,Fees,WeekOfMonth,StartDate,EndDate,FeesName,[MonthName])
SELECT
 2,  sum(Fees) AS Fees  ,WeekOfMonth,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), StartDate, 103) AS StartDate,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), EndDate, 103) AS EndDate,'Temp Margin ' AS FeesName 
  ,@MonthName AS [MonthName]
  from
  (
 SELECT DISTINCT 
sum((CASE WHEN CNTI_DURHEBDO IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CNTI_DURHEBDO/5 END)*@NumberOfDays)-(CNTI_THPAYE *(CASE WHEN CNTI_DURHEBDO IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CNTI_DURHEBDO/5 END)*1.453*1.21*@NumberOfDays) AS Fees,WeekOfMonth,StartDate,EndDate
FROM SCHHAYS.dbo.WTVTAT TAT
      LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTTIEINT INT 
        ON (
            TAT.TIE_ID = INT.TIE_ID
        ) 
        AND (
            TAT.VTAT_IORDRE = INT.TIEI_ORDRE
        )     
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.PYCONTRAT CC 
        ON TAT.PER_ID = CC.PER_ID 
        AND TAT.CNT_ID = CC.CNT_ID     
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.CMTIERS T 
        ON TAT.TIE_ID = T.TIE_ID    
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTMISS M 
        ON CC.PER_ID = M.PER_ID 
        AND CC.CNT_ID = M.CNT_ID     
    LEFT JOIN
    ##WTCNTIWeek COT1 
        ON M.PER_ID = COT1.PER_ID 
        AND M.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID    
    INNER JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTPRH AS PRH 
        ON M.PER_ID = PRH.PER_ID 
        AND M.CNT_ID = PRH.CNT_ID 
        AND M.TIE_ID = PRH.TIE_ID     
    INNER JOIN
    ##tempStartEndWeekDates AS Tsed 
        ON     PRH_DTEDEBSEM>=Tsed.StartDate 
        AND PRH_DTEFINSEM<=Tsed.EndDate     
    LEFT JOIN
    SCHHAYS.dbo.WTSCCT C 
        ON CC.RGPCNT_ID = C.RGPCNT_ID 
        AND CC.PER_ID = C.PER_ID 
        AND CC.CNT_ID = C.CNT_ID   
    INNER JOIN
    ##TempHaysStaffWeek HF 
        ON C.VAPO_CODE = HF.onetouch  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
group by
WeekOfMonth,StartDate,EndDate,CNTI_THPAYE,CNTI_DURHEBDO)t
GROUP BY WeekOfMonth,StartDate,EndDate
```

Comment: too many joins I guess

Comment: How many rows it works with?

Comment: Don't tell me that's made by a human, I wanna barf. The query is seriously not the only problem here. The relational design needs a good shaking, the naming needs to go into the bin. Then, make sure you have properly maintained indices and statistics. After all that, you may ask to optimize your query.

Comment: I am working on database that I can't make changement like index creation ...

Comment: In some cases then, it might help to create a temporary table that does have proper indices. Aside from that you may want to refrain from putting everything in a single query and maintain intermediate results in a temporary table, with or without an index depending on what you plan to do with it.